# Return Value from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
  $change=.07;
  $coins=array(
".01"=>"1 Penny",
".02"=>"2 Pennys",
".03"=>"3 Pennys",
".04"=>"4 Pennys",
".05"=>"5 Pennys",
".06"=>"6 Pennys",
".07"=>"7 Pennys",
".08"=>"8 pennys",
".09"=>"9 Pennys",
".10"=>"1 Dime",
".11"=>"1 Dimes and 1 Penny",
".12"=>"1 Dime and 2 Pennys",
".13"=>"1 Dime and 3 Pennys",
".14"=>"1 Dime and 4 Pennys",
".15"=>"1 Dime and 5 Pennys",
".16"=>"1 Dime and 6 Pennys",
".17"=>"1 Dime and 7 Pennys", 
".18"=>"1 Dime and 8 Pennys",
".19"=>"1 Dime and 9 Pennys",
".20"=>"2 Dimes",
".21"=>"2 Dimes and 1 Penny",
".22"=>"2 Dimes and 2 Pennys",
".23"=>"2 Dimes and 3 pennys",
".24"=>"2 Dimes and 4 Penny",
".25"=>"1 Quarter",
".26"=>"1 Quarter and 1 Penny",
".27"=>"1 Quarter 2 Pennys",
".28"=>"1 Quarter 3 Pennys",
".29"=>"1 Quarter and 4 Pennys",
".30"=>"1 Quarter and 5 Pennys",
".31"=>"1 Quarter and 6 Pennys",
".32"=>"1 Quarter and 7 Pennys",
".33"=>"1 Quarter and 8 Pennys",
".34"=>"1 Quarter and 9 Pennys",
".35"=>"1 Quarter and 1 Dime",
  );
  ?>
```

How do I get $change to be displayed as the second value for an array. So if $change was .25 I would want it to print "1 Quarter". Also in my actual code $change changes each time you run it.

Answer (score 1):

You access a particular element of an array with the square bracket syntax, [as described in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing):

```
echo $coins[$change];
```

Comment: and `$change` should be a string so the value needs to be quoted i.e. `$change = '.07';`

Comment: $change is actually a formula that displays how much change you get back if you put in a random amount of money into a vending machine.

Comment: $change=("$totaldollars-($return*.65)");

Comment: 65 cents per machine item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($coins as $index => $value){
   if($index == $change){
     print $value;
   }
}
```

Here is working code

http://ideone.com/gtKIIz